# Importance of Polynomial Time Approximation algorithm for special case

Tags: reference-request, algorithms, approximation-algorithms

I am an MSc student, searching for an interesting topic in operations research for NP-hard problems. I need your opinion and recommendation about: "Searching a polynomial time approximation algorithm for the special case of facility layout problem: single row equidistant facility layout."

Regarding the literature, there is no polynomial time approximation algorithm for this problem, only heuristic, metaheuristic, and exact algorithms (solve up to n=35). My inquires are:

Is this topic interesting in scientific research?
What are the most expectations of results for such an algorithm to be acceptable for publication?
Any recommendations for journals names in this scope?

Comment: Welcome to OR.SE. Please don't re-ask a question by deleting your [previous question](https://or.stackexchange.com/questions/7296/polynomial-time-approximation-algorithm-for-special-case). Instead, you can edit your question if you wish to add anything to your post. Note that questions such as "interesting in scientific research" are generally quite broad, as research is always interesting to *some* people. It might be helpful if you could summarise any literature searches/reviews you have done so far in relation to your project.